# Java. Multiple while conditions and boolean

Tags: java

I am trying to do a school project and I'm having problems; my code is:

```
    public class Class {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
        int code = 0, i = 0;
        boolean error = true;
        //Start of program
        System.out.println("Inputs ------------------");
        //Ask for input
        do {
                System.out.print("Code: ");
                code = lector.nextInt();
                if ( code < 0 || code > 2000) {
                    error = false;
                } i = i + 1;
        } while (!error || i < 3);

        if (error) {...rest of the program
```

My problem is that I need to exit the loop if the input is > 0 & < 2000, and I need to stop executing the program if the user exceed 3 intents.

Any help would be very apreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
while (!error || i < 3);
```

should be

```
while (!error && i < 3);
```

You want to continue looping while `error` is `false` **and** `i < 3`. Also `i = i + 1;` can be written as `i++` (or with a preincrement). So you could do

```
boolean valid = false;
do {
    System.out.print("Code: ");
    code = lector.nextInt();
    if (code > 0 && code < 2000) {
        valid = true;
    }
    i++;
} while (!valid && i < 3);
```

Comment: I agree with you but then if I enter 0, I get out of the loop. And 0 shouldn't be accepted.

Comment: Then `if ( code < 0 || code > 2000) {` should be `if ( code <= 0 || code >= 2000) {` It's doing what you told it to do.

Comment: Ok, and for example if my 1st choice is number 5, how can I make it exit the loop? considering 5 is between 0 and 2000 and so the boolean is declared true.

Comment: So I need to exit the loop only if a number between 0 and 2000 is inserted and if the user exceeds 3 intents to stop the loop and the program.